# How to link a work load item with a commited change?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I am working with Git for Visual Studio Online

1. I added a Product Back Log item.
2. I added some files & commited the change. (It did not linked for some reason)
3. I made some more commits to the project & synced.

> My 1st change was not linked with the Back log item & it still shows
>   as pending under tasks.

How do I link the work item with my first commit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally to link a commit to a work item you just reference the work item number in the commit message, for example `git commit -am "related to PBI #1234"`. If it didn't work, you may have made a typo in the commit message.

Now, given you have already pushed your changes, amending your earlier comment to change the message would require an interactive rebase and pushing the result of that would be a bad thing (I'm assuming the repo is shared).

What you can do instead is go to the work item and under the Links tab, click the Link To... icon to add a new link.  Select 'Commit' and then enter the SHA1 of the commit you want to link to.

[image]

Don't worry if you don't know the SHA1. Just use the `...` button to browse your history and select the commit you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks Richard. That was really helpful. I managed to find the 'commit' option under new links in online web portal but could not find it in Visual Studio 2013 team explorer. The Commit option is not listed in the dropdown.

Comment: Huh. I never noticed that.

Comment: For reference, I added a bug on Connect for it. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/814222/cannot-link-a-work-item-to-a-git-commit-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: Thanks. Is it really a bug? I mistakenly took changeset for a commit. I thought they were the same.